# Prove that every finitely generated subgroup of a totally ordered group can be totally ordered.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated, well-orders

> Prove that every finitely generated subgroup of a totally ordered group can be totally ordered. A group can be totally ordered if there is a total order $\leq $ on that group.

Is the proof of this trivial? What facts should I use to prove this? I only have second year abstract algebra knowledge and never learned about ordered groups or finitely generated groups before but I know their definitions. I am just unsure whether there are theorems, properties, or lemmas for such groups to help prove this fact.

Should I use Zorn's lemma?

Comment: I'd say that every (finitely generated or not) subgroup of an ordered group is alreday ordered by the inherited order

Comment: It is trivial, there's no Zorn's lemma. The hypothesis "finitely generated" is useless